# Webkit Update in JAVAFX

Tags: java, webview, webkit, javafx-2

Is it possible to update the **webkit** in the **javafx** **netbeans**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Source Code for Open Source Software Components: JavaFX

[Modified Webkit source code](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/opensource/webkit-1667084.html)

Answer (score 2):

[Java snapshot releases](http://jdk8.java.net/download.html) generally utilize more recent versions of webkit than [Java standard releases](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html), so you could try a snapshot release and see if it exposes the WebKit functionality you seek.

---

There are currently no instructions provided by the JavaFX team on how you might yourself integrate an updated or modified WebKit version into JavaFX.  I think any attempts to do so will require the Java portions of the JavaFX web node to be open sourced as there is likely a tight JNI based integration between the Java code and native code for the web node.  Perhaps such instructions might be provided when the JavaFX web node is completely open sourced.  You could request details from the [open-jfx mailing list](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/mailman/listinfo/openjfx-dev) on how to do this as well as an eta for complete open sourcing.